# One time processings of usercontrol when it is wrapped inside updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Traditional way of initializing controls with the values from session state as below -

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["sessionId"] != null)
            {
                //initialize controls
            }
        }
```

Exhibits unexpected behavior when **user control is wrapped inside update panel**.

I need to populate usercontrol textBox values first time from session state. And subsequent loading of these controls values should be populated from viewState.

How do you handle this scenario. Do you think **Page.IsAsync** will be helpful for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsPostback` property returns `true` even if postback fired from control, placed in an UpdatePanel. So it's ok to use `IsPostBack` property for control initializing on first page load.

By the way `Page.IsAsync` property serves for absolutely different purpose, not for detecting asynchronous postbacks. If you need to detect asynchronous postback from UpdatePanel, check `ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack` property